# Error message when using psych::ICC: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, psych

I would like to compute the ICC for a regression model (done using lmer function), but I always get this error message:

> Error in if (n.obs < n.obs.original) message("Warning, missing data were found for ",  :
> argument is of length zero

Here is the function I used:

```r
ICC(model1, missing = TRUE, alpha = .05,lmer = TRUE,check.keys = FALSE)
```

What I don't understand is that the ICC function should be able to handle missing values. This is why I have used the package "`psych and not the package` irr`...

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal dataset that reproduces the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/5805670)? Because without it, it's hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Also, it seems that there simply are no observations found. The line where it fails simply tests whether `n.obs < n.obs.original`. The latter is likely the number of rows of some input. The former is likely what remains. It says that the argument is of length zero, which likely means that `n.obs` is zero. Something is fishy.

Comment: Oh ok thank you fro your answer. That is maybe because the output of my regression model is not a matrix nor a data frame. Do you if I can convert the output into a matrix. I found the output using the "lmer" function.

Comment: Honestly, it would be a lot easier to help out if you provide a dataset that reproduces the error ;)

Comment: Oh so I think i understand where the error comes from (sorry i dont even know how to provide a simple data set that ressemble the one i have ^^). So I have 4 regression models, and each of them is actually a "class 4". So I think what I need to do is create a data set for each of those models, so I need to convert those class 4 output into a data set or matrix. Do you know how to do that ? :) thank's a lot for your help!!